# (PIE) déḱm̥ vs déḱm̥t (ten)

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, numerals

**In short** : what's the final *-t* in *déḱm̥t*?

**Full details :**
The [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) root for *ten* is traditionally defined as *déḱm̥/déḱm̥t*(ᵃ). The final *-t* may be analyzed as a casual ending, e.g. [as a "collective form"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%C3%A9%E1%B8%B1m%CC%A5); Szemerényi describes déḱm̥ as derived from *déḱm̥t*(ᵇ).

The final *-t* is required by various languages, like OCS *desętĭ* and Lithuanian *dešimt*(ᵃ). Likewise, according to Don Ringe, the Proto-Germanic form for *ten* is derived from *déḱm̥t*, surfaced as *déḱm̥d*(ᶜ), hence *tekun*(ᵈ) leading to Gothic *taíhun*(ᵉ).

**My question** : I would like to know the details behind this *-t* : if it's a collective form (["marking collective number (group of ten)"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de%C5%A1imt)), is there any other example of a PIE word using -t as a collective form? The only way I know to create collective PIE forms is (for direct cases) by adding [the ending *-h₂*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals#Grammatical_categories) to the stem.

Any help, any reference would be appreciated !

---

related question [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/786/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-pie-roots-dek%E1%B9%83-and-k%E1%B9%83t%C3%B3m?rq=1).

---

(a) See e.g. (Szemerényi) Introduction to Indo-European Linguistics, 8.5.2 p.223

(b) (Szemerényi) Introduction to Indo-European Linguistics, 8.5.3 p.226
[Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/déḱm̥ (Wikipedia)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%C3%A9%E1%B8%B1m%CC%A5)

(c) Don Ringe, From Proto-Indo-European to Proto-Germanic, 2.2.4(iv) p.20

(d) Don Ringe, From Proto-Indo-European to Proto-Germanic, 3.2.2(i) p.81

(e) Don Ringe, From Proto-Indo-European to Proto-Germanic, 3.2.2(ii) p.87

Comment: Don'get confused with Slavic (and possibly Baltic?) languages. Our numerals from 5-10 are derived from ordinals of the original numerals and all end with -t because of that (also they have rather unusual syntax because of this).

Comment: @Eleshar : thanks, I didn't know. Is there any online reference describing the way OCS numerals have been made ?

Comment: I can try looking up something but it is fairly easily visible even in modern Czech - you have *penkwe/pemnk-to-s* - *pě-t*; *sweks/sweks-to-s* - *šes-t*; *septm/septm-m-os* - *sedm* (cf. *hebdomos*); *h3ektó/h3ektow-o-s* - *osm*; *h1newn/h1newn* (cf. *nin-th*) - *devě-t* (probably from earlier *nevě-t*); *dekm/dekm-m-os* (cf. *ten-th*) - *dese-t*

Comment: Looking at my comment, I was obviously incorrect - not all the mentioned numerals end with -t (but all developed from the ordinals - this is also evidenced by the strange syntax, numerals 2-4 work like regular adjectives and are followed by plural; 5+ is behaves like a head of NP in Nom/Acc where it is followed always by plural genitive). Reg. the developement though, note also the principle of paired rhyming in eg. Czech: tři/čtyři; pět/šest, sedm/osm, devět/deset.

Comment: In Phrygian *dekmoutais* means *'tenth'*, not plain ten (10). Unfortunately, we lack the word for plain 10, which makes it hard to pin point the function of -t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only language to preserve both is Sanskrit: *dáśa-* 'ten' ~ *daśát*- f. 'a set of ten; decade'.

A similar form is Lith. *dešimtìs* which reflects a Balto-Slavic consonant stem, as shown by gen.pl. *dešimtų̃*, gen.sg. *dešimtès*, dat.sg. *dešimti*:

> *Ponas … pasirodo dešimti savo apaštalams.* 'The lord appeared to his ten apostles.' (Bretke, Postilla II, 35)

Furthermore, the OLith. and dial. indeclinable form *dešim̃s* probably represents a fossilized nom.sg. *deḱm-t-s. The Lith. form is therefore identical to the Sanskrit one. The same formation is found in Old Prussian *dessimpts* (II) 'ten'. Standard Lithuanian *dẽšimt* could be from *deḱm with -t- on the basis of this form (dial. *dešim̃* 'ten' is actually attested).

Gm. *tehun has restored -n- on the basis of ordinal *tehunþas. PIE *deḱm should have given *tehu with a lost *-m, a Verner variant of which, *tegu is preserved in the suffix fif-*ty*, OE -*tig*, OHG -*zig*.

It appears that IE *deḱm was an indeclinable numeral like *penkʷe, *sueḱs, etc., while *deḱm-t- was a derived feminine t-stem, possibly meaning 'a group or set of ten', cf. the Sanskrit meaning, which developed into a cardinal number in Baltic.

The t-suffix is also found in the decades, cf. *penkʷe-dḱomt- > Skt. pañcāśát- f., Gr. πεντήκοντα 'fifty'.

I am not aware of any cases where a t-suffix has a collective function, however the function of the suffix here is rather nominalizing, i.e. *deḱm 'ten' vs *deḱmts 'a ten'.

Comment: Why the difference in the reflexes of *ḱ in the two Sanskrit words?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied the Proto-Indo-Iranian reconstruction rather than the Sanskrit form. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you're ready to believe it means 'two hands' in which case the 't' is the last letter of the root of *komtos > PG *xamðaz > NE 'hand'.

Comment: lol  " `*komtos` > PG `*xamðaz` "  is a common, standard and still current Abanian for **legs** not hands.

Comment: If it is from the root for hand, it is a suffix. Because the word for right hand came from the root for "right" dec-.